# Deploy plotly dash on IIS

Tags: python, iis, plotly-dash

I am trying to deploy a plotly dash to IIS.
First I followed the instructions in the link: 
[Flask on IIS - James Polera](https://netdot.co/2015/03/09/flask-on-iis/) 
then when i use this script it is works:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from FastCGI via IIS!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

but when i use this script it doesn't works for dash:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1('Hello Dash!'),
                                html.Div('Dash: Web Dashboard with python'),
                                dcc.Graph(id='example',
                                        figure={'data':[
                                            {'x':[1,2,3],'y':[4,1,3],'type':'bar','name':'SF'},
                                            {'x':[1,2,3],'y':[2,4,5],'type':'bar','name':'NYC'}
                                                        ],
                                                'layout':{'title':'BAR PLOTS'}
                                                })
                                ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

i get this error:

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dash
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dash import Dash, no_update  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 23, in <module>
    import plotly
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from plotly import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\__init__.py", line 100161, in <module>
    import ipywidgets
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from IPython import get_ipython
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 15, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 64, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import io
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 94, in <module>
    stdin = IOStream(sys.stdin, fallback=devnull)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 38, in __init__
    for meth in filter(clone, dir(stream)):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 37, in clone
    return not hasattr(self, meth) and not meth.startswith('_')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 81, in closed
    return self.stream.closed
ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
```

Someone can help, for two days now that I've been trying to find a solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should expose the Flask object, not the Dash object. Hence the code would be something like,

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import Flask

server = Flask(__name__)  # object to be referenced by WSGI handler
app = dash.Dash(server=server)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1('Hello Dash!'),
                                html.Div('Dash: Web Dashboard with python'),
                                dcc.Graph(id='example',
                                        figure={'data':[
                                            {'x':[1,2,3],'y':[4,1,3],'type':'bar','name':'SF'},
                                            {'x':[1,2,3],'y':[2,4,5],'type':'bar','name':'NYC'}
                                                        ],
                                                'layout':{'title':'BAR PLOTS'}
                                                })
                                ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

Note that in my code example, the Flask app object is called `server`. Hence with my naming convention, the WSGI_HANDLER value should be changed to `app.server`.