# how to deploy a python web app with windows authentication

Tags: python, windows, authentication, web, plotly-dash

I created a python web application using Dash. I want to deploy it with windows authentication. I guess the process will be like when users try to access my web app, I need to get the username first, and check if the username is in a valid group via ldap. If the username is in some certain group, the app will be loaded so that users can see it, otherwise, an error page will be loaded. It's not like a login process that users type their usernames and passwords within the app. It should be an authorization happened before the app is loaded to the users. My question is which web server I should use to deploy my web app in a windows system, and how can I config the web server. Or web server cannot support this process. Then what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar project some time ago. It is possible to configure IIS server, if you want to run your app on Windows.

- You should be able to deploy your app on IIS using [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60322634/deploy-plotly-dash-on-iis)
- Then you need to configure [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/providers/add)
- Last step is to set up rules in [Authorization module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authorization/).

I have spend a lot of time looking for solution and trying to make it work. There is no one simple instuction how to do this, so if you will have any problem with this I will try to edit my answer and explain missing parts.